# How to filter `null` from the type of a single object field for an array of such objects?

Tags: typescript

All the code below can be inspected in this [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUAk6CaassIC8oANoByAF6Q2+-vvidIZ0PtQT4Nu5jKRr5gGYcy+gLoBuRWVLNVBOdkRBAC5QAApwxGkTUAAfMPZoaABKXV9QHV0ABn4ARn4AJn4AZn4AFgCglVDDKiJufNANQQA6RAYCWNiNfgos-IA+OIBvTtQyfgSYhMFdCjyAXyyswMUQTopEAmgUcMzQWGxYAGtQbnhIQU47UGxoAmDVGgvIa8huADkMtASh0WgQ2t0PBRoAoyIMZglQJsJulEKAAIRaHSnbI7PaoQgoZjsBhkdp3B5PGivAigSDybBkD6hTiWQGZBjSY4dAA8OHGsQAbgxoOxIDEcFkYsLRShRP82UDOcc+ZMtJMZWKMVj0pkdk0vpcrn92dByqDWn9IdDYfDUUixuqwoqOVzIPEIlsdkA).

I have 2 arrays that I want to zip together:

```
const strs = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

// modelling a case where the type  is `(T | null)[]`
// but we know no element is null
const nums: (number | null)[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

const zipped = strs.map((str, i) => ({ str, num: nums[i] }));
```

The type of `zipped` becomes `{ str: string, num: number | null }[]}`.

I know `num` will never be null so I want to remove `null` from the type. Since it's an array I can use `filter`:

```
const checkedNull1 = zipped.filter(({ num }) => num !== null);
```

That didn't work, the type is still the same.

Using `NonNullable<T>` and a type predicate instead:

```
const nonNullable = <T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> => value !== null;

const checkedNull2 = zipped.filter(({ num }) => nonNullable(num));
```

But the type still doesn't work.

Comment: I removed all the project specific stuff to clarify the question

Comment: `const zipped2 = strs.map((str, i) => ({ str, num: Number(nums[i]) }));` has a type of `{ str: string, num: number }`. you can achieve similar using `const zipped2 = strs.map((str, i) => ({ str, num: nums[i] ?? 0 }));`. If "you know num will never be null", try `const zipped2 = strs.map((str, i) => ({ str, num: nums[i]! }));` (note the `!`), but if you know it won't be null why not change the type of `nums` to `number[]`?

Comment: Oh. Somehow I forgot about the '!' operator... It does the trick, thx